# oracle compound Check constraint

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, check-constraints

Say I want to allow in a table column only strings that begin with a numeral and should not contain '$' in it. How would a check constraint on this table look like?

Comment: For what version of Oracle?  10g+ supports regex...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Oracle 10g+, you can use Oracle's regex functionality in a CHECK constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT col_regx CHECK REGEXP_LIKE(column_name,'^[[:digit:]]{1}[^$]*$'));
```

### References:

- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_regular_expressions_constraints_updates_columns.htm
- http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html
- http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use Oracle's Regular Expressions. Useful link for syntax requirement for the corresponding IF constraint can be found below

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

Answer (score 0):

The regex would look like `^\d[^$]*$`

I don't know Oracle so forgive me if this doesn't actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT col_regx CHECK (substr(column_name,1,1) between '0' and '9' and column_name not like '%$%')

(not tested but probably faster than a regex)